# dynamic table creation table dividing lines of tables do not align bootstrap angular

Tags: css, angular, css-tables

I am using bootstrap and angular 4.

My html code is as follows

```
<div *ngIf="showtable" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <table class="table" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Category</th>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Capability</th>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Adopt</th>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Trial</th>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Assess</th>
            <th class="text-center" scope="col">Scope</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
      <table *ngFor="let t of object" class="table table-bordered" width="100%">
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let d of t.table; let i = index">
          <td  class="text-center">
            <p *ngIf="i === t.showindex">{{d.category}}</p>
          </td>
          <td  class="text-center">
            <p>{{d.capability}}</p>
          </td>
          <td  class="text-center">
            <p>{{d.adopt}}</p>
          </td>
          <td  class="text-center">
            <p>{{d.trial}}</p>
          </td>
          <td  class="text-center">
            <p>{{d.assess}}</p>
          </td>
          <td  class="text-center">
            <p>{{d.hold}}</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>

      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this creates the following tables based on the model I am using in my ts

[image]

both tables the lines between table rows columns etc need to line up.

my css is currently empty and just to make it clear here is my ts

```
object = [
    {
      table: [
        {
          category: 'Dev thing',
          capability: 'Data Access',
          adopt: 'Spring Data',
          trial: '',
          assess: '',
          hold: ''
        },
        {
          category: 'Dev thing',
          capability: 'Data Access',
          adopt: 'Spring Data',
          trial: '',
          assess: '',
          hold: ''
        },
        {
          category: 'Dev thing',
          capability: 'Data Access',
          adopt: 'Spring Data',
          trial: '',
          assess: '',
          hold: ''
        },
      ],
      showindex: 1
    },

    {
      table: [
        {
          category: 'Dev thing',
          capability: 'Data Access',
          adopt: 'Spring Data',
          trial: 'stuff',
          assess: 'stuff',
          hold: 'stuff'
        },
        {
          category: 'Dev thing',
          capability: 'Data Access',
          adopt: 'Spring Data',
          trial: '',
          assess: '',
          hold: ''
        },
        {
          category: 'Dev thing',
          capability: 'Data Access',
          adopt: 'Spring Data',
          trial: '',
          assess: '',
          hold: ''
        },
      ],
      showindex: 1
    }
  ];
```

what css do I need to add or modifications do I need to make to make what I want happen?

update:

so its seems that I need to set a width part of each td to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes.according to your array tbody looping is enough no need to loop table. I have added border to table in order to get a clear view.

```
 <div *ngIf="true" class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">

          <table class="table table-bordered" border="1" width="100%">
             <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="text-center" style="text-align:left"><p>Category</p></th>
                <th class="text-center" style="text-align:left" ><p>Capability</p></th>
                <th class="text-center" style="text-align:left" ><p>Adopt</p></th>
                <th class="text-center" style="text-align:left" ><p>Trial</p></th>
                <th class="text-center" style="text-align:left" ><p>Assess</p></th>
                <th class="text-center" style="text-align:left" ><p>Scope</p></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody  *ngFor="let t of object">
            <tr *ngFor="let d of t.table; let i = index">
              <td  class="text-center">
                <p *ngIf="i === t.showindex">{{d.category}}</p>
              </td>
              <td  class="text-center">
                <p>{{d.capability}}</p>
              </td>
              <td  class="text-center">
                <p>{{d.adopt}}</p>
              </td>
              <td  class="text-center">
                <p>{{d.trial}}</p>
              </td>
              <td  class="text-center">
                <p>{{d.assess}}</p>
              </td>
              <td  class="text-center">
                <p>{{d.hold}}</p>
              </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
         </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: very impressive! you have solved many pf my problems. Thank you!